# Como trocar o id de uma coluna pelo nome na mesma tabela no MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Quero dar um select e ao invés de receber o numero_depto_superior quero o nome dele que é nm_depto. Como posso fazer isso?

```
SELECT d.id_numero_depto, d.nm_depto, d.id_numero_depto_superior FROM tb_depto AS d;
```

Comment: Você quer alterar o nome da coluna de "id_numero_depto_superior" para "nm_depto" no retorno da sua consulta?

Comment: Sim, o nm_depto correspondente

Comment: Você vai precisar fazer um relacionamento, qual é o nome da tabela que terá a informação do nm_depto?

Comment: a tabela é a mesma para os dois.

Comment: Isac não entendi

Answer (score -1):

Consegui, esse foi o código:

```
select d1.id_numero_depto, d1.nm_depto, d2.nm_depto from tb_depto d1, tb_depto d2 where d1.id_numero_depto_superior = d2.id_numero_depto and d1.id_numero_depto_superior is not null;
```